# How to write the result of IGrouping?

Tags: c#, linq

I wrote the following LINQ query:

```
public IEnumerable DailyReturns()
{
    var a =  from exec in executions
             group exec by exec.TimeStamp.Date into execGroup
             select new { TimeStamp = execGroup.Key, CashFlow = execGroup.Sum(e => e.CashFlow())};
    return a;
}
```

I get a Unhandled Exception: `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`
 when I try to:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime, double> p in s.Executions.DailyReturns())
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Key.ToString() + ',' + p.Value.ToString());
}
```

Executions is a `List<Execution>`.

Execution class has the following relevant fields:

```
public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
public double CashFlow()
{ 
    return Price * Quantity * -1;
}
```

Comment: `select new {}` produces an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) - it is *not* a `KeyValuePair` so you can't cast it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an anonymous type rather than `KeyValuePair<DateTime,double>`.

You can fix this by adding an appropriate type to the method:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime,double>> DailyReturns() {
    return   from exec in executions
             group exec by exec.TimeStamp.Date into execGroup
             select new KeyValuePair<DateTime,double>(
                 execGroup.Key
             ,   execGroup.Sum(e => e.CashFlow())
             );
}
```